# Eclipse stop generating R.java

Tags: android, eclipse

Today, I update ADT to 22.0.1.v201305230001--685705, and found that Eclipse stopped generating R.java. I believed that it is problem of Eclipse, because I create a whole new clean android project, and I cannot even run it as android application. I cannot find any files under gen folder.
The version of Eclipse is 4.2.2, is there any way to solve it?

I try to use Eclipse 4.3 with the latest version ADT, but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem.

Open up the android SDK Manager, and install the new android build tools. Without this you will no longer be able to build anything.

For some reason they have seperated them, and a lot of people are not noticing.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I found the tool and is installing it now.

Comment: :) no problem. I am not sure why they split them. I spent a while figuring that one out too.

Comment: Thanks you save another 1 hour of my time. I don't understand why these tools are not bundled together.

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting bin folder and clean the project..and In Eclipse, under the Project menu, is an option build automatically. That would help you build the R.java file everytime modifications are made. The Clean... option is also there under Project It seems to be a common issue with many different answers

Comment: Thanks, but I believe that it is not that kind of problems. I've tried all the ways I used to solve R.java problem, but now I cannot even run a clean project which just been created......

Comment: it has been very common project , even i faced it but cleaning will help you ..try few times and if then also it did help out then i think u post mail to me may be i can help u

Answer (score 2):

Update android-sdk, I think sdk need `Android SDK Build-tools`. For update it follow some steps--
 Go to **Window->Android SDK Manager.**
 Update and Install all tools (**Android SDK Tools, Android SDK Platform-tools,Android SDK Build-tools**) which are in `Tools` folder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Check the xml files of your layout whether they are properly saved with no error or not.*

I have faced similar problem that suddenly R.java is disappeared and eclipse could not regenerate it after building SDK. I checked SDK manager and saw that Android SDK build tool is perfectly installed. Finally, I have noticed that there are some errors in xml files. After fixing and saving those, R.java generated automatically in my case.

Comment: this was my problem. I had deleted some values from the strings file, and I didn't have any errors related to that in the list of problems (only R file missing). Since this was a new activity, I just deleted everything that was related to that new activity, and recreated it.